# Windows Phone 8 Stop bing from opening when searching bing in webbrowser

Tags: c#, url, windows-phone-8, browser

When trying to search a query in bing a the WebBrowser compenant in windows phone 8. How do I prevent it from opening to other programs such as the search and internet explorer.

Here is the code which will switch to the search page but I would like to stay in my app.

```
Browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bing.com/search?q=" + "hello", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Thank you in advance :)

If you need any more details please comment and I will be happy to explain in further detail :)

Comment: You mean is it currently opening the IE browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the bing website in the browser element use this code:

```
Browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bing.com/search?q=" + "hello", UriKind.Absolute));
```